# DirectoryDialog in swt does not respect the text field at the bottom of the dialog

Tags: java, swt

DirectoryDialog in swt has a text field at the bottom labeled Folder:
It shows the name of the directory selected in the tree above. However text entered in this field (to change the directory name) is always ignored. Any suggestions to disable this field or make it work so it change the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

With `DirectoryDialog`, the "Folder" field is a read/write field, but I think it may always be read-only in nature.  If anyone knows a way to modify this behavior or to make the field read-only, I would be interested as well.

While this is not quite what you're looking for, you might be able to use `FileDialog`, which allows you to navigate the file system and select or *enter* a file.  Granted, this will prompt the user for a file instead of a directory, so it might be not applicable in your case.

If it's useful, here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FileDialogExample.htm) of using `FileDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported eclipe bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307351